# Imported Obj and MTL files do not display correctly

Tags: rendering, mesh, import

I am a bit of a noob at blender.
I have an Obj file and a Mtl file, which Windows' default model viewer can put the two together with no issue, so I know they're linked.
When I import the Obj file, they both import in the list, but the model appears black with 0 light source, and white with one. I've tried fiddling with the diffuse, but no avail. The block-white colour does change if I change the light source.
I've done my best to try and sort the issue by looking at the forums, but now I've come unstuck despite my best efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: The thing is, reading this post doesn't help either. I just simply want to see the material to show on the model, so I can bake it and turn it into a UV map. But I can't get it to show, so I can't proceed.

Comment: Without knowing more about your model, bottom line is that you have to create new materials using the provided textures targeting your desired render engine

Comment: Is this in cycles or blender internal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing MTLs for your OBJs you need to make sure both the MTL and supporting UV texture JPGs/PNGs are selected during upload
Otherwise your model will be missing textures ,
 another noob here , just read this in a chat though, hope it helps